# Spring Boot DDD - How to place entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, domain-driven-design

Good afternoon. I'm trying to implement DDD architecture and use two databases - PostgreSQL and MongoDB, but I don't quite understand how and where I should store entities.

Let's start with my knowledges.

1. My Project must contains 4 layers: presentation, application, domain and infrastructure.
2. Presentation layer must contains controllers and dtos.
3. Application layer must contains services which processing dtos and do business logic then return dtos (optional).
4. Domain layer must contains entities, aggregates and repositories interfaces.
5. Infrastructure need to realize repositories, add configurations and others instruments. Correct me if it need and add more information about this layers.

Am I understanding DDD correctly?

I found an example of a project where DDD architecture is implemented and there entities are distributed in two layers - domain and infrastructure. I implemented my application in the same way (attached screenshot). However, in other examples where DDD is implemented, the entities are in only one instance in the domain layer. What is the correct way to place the entities?

[image: Project structure]